# ERR TOO MANY REDIRECTS - When redirecting user based on their selected city

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, http-redirect

So I have a drop-down select that changes a custom field's value in their user profile based on their selected city. If a user chooses 'Detroit' for example, Detroit is then stored in their profile and that data is then used to redirect the customer based on their selection.

An issue I am running into seems to be if the customer selects a NEW different city on the homepage, or on a page deeper in the directory they get met with the TOO MANY REDIRECTS loop.

I understand WHY, I just can't seem to see where my issues are that are causing it.

Any help appreciated. Even if there is an easier, cleaner way to accomplish this.

```
add_action('wp_footer' , 'city_redirects');
function city_redirects() {
        global $current_user;
        global $wp;
        $current_url = home_url( add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request ) );
        wp_get_current_user(); // wordpress global variable to fetch logged in user info
        $userID = $current_user->ID; // logged in user's ID
        $metalocation_display = get_user_meta($userID, 'location_select', true); // stores the value of logged in user's meta data for 'test'.
        $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    //chicago REDIRECTS
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $metalocation_display == 'chicago' && strpos($url,'chicago') == false) {
        header('Location: example.com/chicago/' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        }
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $metalocation_display !== 'chicago' && strpos($url,'chicago') == true) {
        header('Location: example.com/' . str_replace('chicago', '', 'example.com/chicago') . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        }
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page() && $metalocation_display !== 'chicago' && strpos($url,'chicago') == true) {
        header('Location: example.com/');
        }
    //detroit REDIRECTS
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $metalocation_display == 'detroit' && strpos($url,'detroit') == false) {
        header('Location: example.com/detroit/' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        }
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $metalocation_display !== 'detroit' && strpos($url,'detroit') == true) {
        header('Location: example.com/' . str_replace('detroit', '', 'example.com/detroit') . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        }
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page() && $metalocation_display !== 'detroit' && strpos($url,'detroit') == true) {
        header('Location: example.com/');
        }
    //philadelphia REDIRECTS
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $metalocation_display == 'philadelphia' && strpos($url,'philadelphia') == false) {
        header('Location: example.com/philadelphia/' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        }
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $metalocation_display !== 'philadelphia' && strpos($url,'philadelphia') == true) {
        header('Location: example.com/' . str_replace('philadelphia', '', 'example.com/philadelphia') . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        }
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page() && $metalocation_display !== 'philadelphia' && strpos($url,'philadelphia') == true) {
        header('Location: example.com/');
        }
}
```

Comment: Hooking this to `wp_footer` is way after headers are already sent. If you want this to work, you'll have to hook to something at or before `init`

Comment: @HowardE crazy thing is, it actually works for the most part. Reason being is that the updated meta data needs to be received to dictate how to redirect. The issue is stemming from something to do with the directory specifications I think... but Im not sure.